# Same C++ code compiled on the same machine behaves differently

Tags: c++, qt, dll, crash

I have written a C++ code that uses some of the Qt static libraries.
I compile the code using MSVS2010 (on Windows 7) and then run the created `.exe`-file on a second machine.

I have compiled the exact same code on the same machine 2 different times and the `.exe` code that is generated crashes on the second machine when that machine's (Windows XP) screen saver starts, I have compiled the same code another time (nothing has changed in the code or the compiler or its settings) and the generated `.exe`-file does work fine.

Has anybody an idea on what can cause this?

Is there a way I can debug this issue?
Could the fact that at different times maybe different other programs are open affect the compilation?

Comment: It could be almost anything.  I would suggest debugging the crash like you would any other crash situation.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's almost impossible to tell...

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth I am a beginner in this, what is the best way to debug? If I run the code in debug mode, when it crashes does it give me any info?

Comment: @TJ1: If you run the code in the debugger, yes, it should stop on the line that caused the crash, allowing you to inspect variables etc.

Comment: At a guess I'd say it's heap corruption. Is the crash reproducible? Can you reduce the code to the simplest version that causes the crash? Do you have a tool that can check for memory leaks?

Comment: @Beta what tool I can use to check for memory leaks?

Comment: @Beta I can reduce the code, and the crashes seems to be reproducible as when the screen saver comes up it happens. Can you please let me know what tools are available to check memory leak? I am using MSVS2010, thanks.

Comment: I use valgrind, but that's for UNIX, not Windows. If the reduced source code is small enough to post here we could take a look at it. Is there any way to compile the code on the second machine? I doubt the architectures are incompatible (or it wouldn't work at all), but it's good to eliminate variables.

Comment: @Beta I have reported part of the reduced source code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178857/using-visual-leak-detector

Comment: If this relates to the same application as [this later question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178857/using-visual-leak-detector), then I would say that it's pure luck that it runs on one machine. More than likely the screensaver kicking in is messing with something you deleted which you really shouldn't have. Qt then referring to it fails unsurprisingly. That it works on the other machine is dumb luck in that case. Anyway, just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **not** with the compilation process (it will always produce the same binary provided you didn't change the sources) but with the execution environment.

There seems to be something on your second machine that makes your program crash intermittently (or it could well be that it has nothing to do with that second machine, and that your program crashes intermittently everywhere). To debug that, you may end up having to install a debugging environment on the second machine and hope the problem arises again, or you could also try to reproduce the crash on your development machine.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot install any debugging environment on the second machine.

Comment: @TJ1: So your real question is, "how do I debug something on a machine for which I have no debugger?".  You're not likely to get much an answer, except, "don't try impossible problems".

Comment: @IraBaxter can I debug my code on the machine that I have debugging capabilities for a possible memory leak? I have installed Visual Leak Detector and got some results but cannot interpret them. Can you help me on that? Thanks.

Comment: SO's style suggests you should start another questions to get help with that. (No, I have no skills re Visual Leak Detector).

Comment: @IraBaxter thanks, I started another question based on your suggestion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178857/using-visual-leak-detector

Comment: ... and it looks like you are getting excellent help as a result.