# Using Visual Leak Detector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, memory-leaks, visual-leak-detector

I have C++ code that crashes randomly. In the code I have used some of the Qt libraries. The compiler is MSVS 2010. Based on some suggestions that this could be due to memory leaks, I started looking in this using Visual Leak Detector. I am very new to Visual Leak Detector and memory leak detection.

Here is the code in main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

And also the `MainWindow` constructor looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    ,   m_Inputdevice(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice())
    ,   m_audioInput(0)
    ,   m_input(0)
    ,   m_iVolume(0)
    ,   m_buffer(BufferSize, 0)
    ,   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{  // LINE 23
    ui->setupUi(this);
    initializeAudio(); // LINE 26
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this); 
    udpSocket1 = new QUdpSocket(this);
    ...
    char* str = new char [30]; 
    VLDEnable();
    VLDReportLeaks(); 
}
```

And the destructor is:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete udpSocket;
  delete udpSocket1;
  delete m_audioInput;
  delete ui;
}
```

Based on some suggestions I just installed it and got the following results:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 1 at 0x00CDED68: 12 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (23): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow + 0x59 bytes
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
C8 F9 CD 00    38 FD CD 00    28 3B 6E 02                    ....8... (;n.....



---------- Block 2 at 0x00CDF9C8: 20 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\generatedfiles\ui_mainwindow.h (36): TestProgram.exe!Ui_MainWindow::setupUi + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (26): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
5C 90 DA 00    18 FA CD 00    38 90 DA 00    00 00 CD CD     \....... 8.......
CC FA CD 00                                                  ........ ........


---------- Block 3 at 0x00CDFD38: 20 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\generatedfiles\ui_mainwindow.h (38): TestProgram.exe!Ui_MainWindow::setupUi + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (26): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
24 8F DA 00    88 FD CD 00    00 8F DA 00    00 00 CD CD     $....... ........
3C FE CD 00                                                  <....... ........


---------- Block 4 at 0x026E3B28: 20 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\generatedfiles\ui_mainwindow.h (41): TestProgram.exe!Ui_MainWindow::setupUi + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (26): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
24 8F DA 00    78 3B 6E 02    00 8F DA 00    00 00 CD CD     $...x;n. ........
2C 3C 6E 02                                                  ,<n..... ........


---------- Block 6 at 0x026E4200: 8 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (28): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
34 8D DA 00    50 49 6E 02                                   4...PIn. ........


---------- Block 5 at 0x026E4C90: 12 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (76): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::createAudioInput + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (67): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::initializeAudio
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (28): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
74 91 DA 00    A0 4B 6E 02    78 50 6E 02                    t....Kn. xPn.....


---------- Block 7 at 0x026E54C8: 8 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (29): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
34 8D DA 00    10 55 6E 02                                   4....Un. ........


---------- Block 8 at 0x026E62D8: 30 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
c:\tmp\mainwindow.cpp (33): TestProgram.exe!MainWindow::MainWindow + 0x7 bytes
c:\tmp\main.cpp (7): TestProgram.exe!main + 0xA bytes
c:\myqt\4.8.2\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp (131): TestProgram.exe!WinMain + 0x12 bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (547): TestProgram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x2C bytes
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): TestProgram.exe!WinMainCRTStartup
0x756233AA (File and line number not available): kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12 bytes
0x77139EF2 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63 bytes
0x77139EC5 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36 bytes
Data:
CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD           ........ ........
```

I appreciate any help to find out where the memory leak/s come from based on these results.

Comment: It would be nice to see the code in mainwindow.cpp and main.cpp

Comment: I added the code in `main.cpp`, will trim down the code in `maindindow.cpp` and post it.

Comment: Please show the `MainWindow` constructor as well, and please mark out lines 23 and 26 (the lines pointed out in the messages). Also, please be advices that Qt might allocate memory that is used for the whole of the program, and therefore will not be free'd. This will look like a memory leak but really isn't.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok I will show them in the question.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer based on the above codes is there anything that looks like memory leak? Thanks.

Comment: @TJ1 did you free all the allocations in the destructor ? Also all the  allocations made in intializeAudio()) need to be freed

Comment: anything with `new/malloc` could be a memory leak.. do you free the resources?

Comment: The one on line 23 is very likely from the `ui(new Ui::MainWindow)`. I'm not at home with Qt, but this could be one instance of where it shouldn't be deleted. Or it should and you simply forgot to do it in the destructor.

Comment: I delete everything that is assigned by `new` in the destructor. I have updated my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code of `main.cpp` file -- there are some errors.

There is a rule -- to every `new` must have its `delete`.

In your constructor, strange variable `char* str = new char [30];` is declared, allocated, but never freed.

And what is `m_buffer(BufferSize, 0)` and `m_Inputdevice(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice())`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually you are right the `str` should be freed also you pointed me to the right direction, it turned out that the main reason was `BufferSize`, which was close to boundary I increased it a little and now there is no crash.

Comment: Thats nice! Happy to be helpfull. Be careful about all of your variables! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't explicitly delete your Qt objects if you have set a parent.

[QObjects organize themselves in object trees](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html). Giving Qt widgets and the like a parent, transfers ownership of the widget to that parent. Upon destruction the parent will take care of cleaning its children up. In those instances, your `new` **does not need** a matching `delete`. In fact, if you do so it will cause you problems.

At the very least you don't require

```
delete udpSocket;
delete udpSocket1;
```

Depending on your other code you might not even need

```
delete m_audioInput;
delete ui;
```

Comment: Thanks Bart. The `m_audioInput` is defined as: `m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_Inputdevice, m_format, this);` so you think I should not delete it?

Comment: Your `this` [is the parent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaudioinput.html) in this case. That is now the "owner" of your QAudioInput. So no, you should not delete it.